# Combining two $exists en MongoDB .find

Tags: arrays, mongodb, exists

I would like to find documents that contain some fields, by using `$exists`. In particular, I am interested in two fields: `payload.fields.MDI_CC_DIAG_DTC_LIST` and `payload.asset`.

If I want to find only documents that contain the first one, this is my query:

```
db.getCollection("dtc").find({"payload.fields.MDI_CC_DIAG_DTC_LIST": {$exists: true}}).count()
```

It gives me 2265 documents.

When I try to find documents that contain two fields (the ones described above), I use this code:

```
db.getCollection("dtc").find({"payload.fields.MDI_CC_DIAG_DTC_LIST": {$exists: true}}, {"payload.asset": {$exists: true}}, {multi: true})count()
```

It throws me an error:

Failed to retrieve documents

```
[coches.dtc@ localhost:27017 [direct]] : An error occurred while retrieving documents!

Stacktrace: 
|_/ java.lang.Exception: [coches.dtc@ localhost:27017 [direct]] : An error occurred while retrieving documents!
|____/ Illegal argument: Invalid number of arguments to find().
```

What am I coding wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has couple of issues, try below one :

```
db.getCollection("dtc")
  .find({
    "payload.fields.MDI_CC_DIAG_DTC_LIST": { $exists: true },
    "payload.asset": { $exists: true }
  })
  .count();
```

**Issues :**

1. [.find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html) would take two arguments `.find({...},{...})` first one being filter (All filters against collection go here) & second one is projection (Which is used to either exclude or include certain fields from result documents). Here you're passing in 3 args. But in general when it comes to **node.js** 3rd one could be a callback function but it has nothing to do with actual query being executed on database.
2. There is no such thing called `{multi: true}` on `.find()`. `multi` will be passed as 3rd option/arg to [.update()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update) operations in order to update multiple documents matching filtered criteria.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations and details. It worked

Answer (score 1):

That's just a typo. Instead of adding another property to your query, you've passed it as a second argument to `find`.

Try this:

```
/* ... */ true}}, {"payload.asset" /* ... */
/* ... */ true},   "payload.asset" /* ... */
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you be more specific and edit your answer customizing my code? I am new to Mongo and still learning their gramatical rules...

Comment: Replace the first line with the second. Instead of two objects with one property, you have to make one object with two properties.