# Error when running query using mongolite (R and MongoDB)

Tags: r, mongodb, mongolite

In my localhost y created a database (`coches`) and a collection (`dtc`) in MongoDB. My collection contains more than 2 million documents.

I would like to connect a subset of documents into R. The query I ran in MongoDB was the one of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60869881/combining-two-exists-en-mongodb-find/60870188?noredirect=1#comment107700379_60870188) and I copy/paste here:

```
db.getCollection("dtc")
  .find({
    "payload.fields.MDI_CC_DIAG_DTC_LIST": { $exists: true },
    "payload.asset": { $exists: true }
  })
```

This subset resulted in 2265 documents.

I loaded the `mongolite` package in RStudio to connect MongoDB with R.

```
library(mongolite)
c <- mongo(collection = "dtc", db = "coches")
```

However, when I tried these queries:

```
# query 1
c$find('{
    "payload.fields.MDI_CC_DIAG_DTC_LIST": { $exists: true },
    "payload.asset": { $exists: true }
  }')

# query 2
c$find(query = '{
    "payload.fields.MDI_CC_DIAG_DTC_LIST": { $exists: true },
    "payload.asset": { $exists: true }
  }')
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Invalid JSON object: { "payload.fields.MDI_CC_DIAG_DTC_LIST": { $exists: true }, "payload.asset": { $exists: true } }
```

The original documents are JSON embedded files.

What's wrong in the coding? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

After a while, checking different places, I came across with the problem and therefore could be able to solve it. The problem was that `$exists` must be enclosed with quotation marks (`"$exists"`). So the code would be like this:

```
dtc$find('{ 
        "payload.fields.MDI_CC_DIAG_DTC_LIST" : { 
            "$exists" : true
        }, 
        "payload.asset" : { 
            "$exists" : true
        }
    }')
```